# horizontal scrollbars with slimscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slimscroll

I use slimscroll for my scrolling needs and it works great. Now I have need for horizontal scrolling. A quick google search gives me some results to references in the github source code and some issues which indicates that that horizontal scroll support has been added but nowhere I can I find an example. I've looked in the javascript file expecting to find a flag to switch from vertical to horizontal. Helas nothing so obvious. So my question is it possible if yes, how? An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you consider using custom scrollbar -> http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest version of slimscroll is 1.3.1 (from github repository) and it does not support horizontal scrollbar. Try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) or any scrollbar that supports horizontal scrolling from this [scrollbar comparison table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=sharing).

Comment: thanks for the comparison table. it's a great help!!

Comment: Actually there is a fork of the jquery slimscroll plugin with horizontal support: https://github.com/lanre-ade/jQuery-slimScroll

Answer (score 1):

Now you can atualize your plug-in on the [SlimScroll git repository](https://github.com/lanre-ade/jQuery-slimScroll), and just use the code below to instance your slimScroll

```
$('#testDiv').slimscroll({
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    axis: 'both'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slimscroll with both axes examples using Bootstrap 4.

[Click here](https://learncodeweb.com/jquery/horizontal-and-vertical-scroll-bar-with-bootstrap-4/#.XG6WPITaThE.reddit) to see the online working examples.

Answer (score -2):

I implemented ngSlimscroll, the rewritten version of the original slimscroll in AngularJS. It also supports horizontal scrolling. See the [demo](http://demo.jankuri.com/ngSlimscroll) for example.

Comment: Thanks dude! I have posted a question for you on you on github.

Comment: I've tried your module, but it broke my CSS. Can't be used without pain.

Comment: This plugin is poorly built - you cannot scroll without highlighting the contents.

Comment: This works great! But one thing - when you resize the window nothing gets adjusted - you should have another option when resizing the window, adjust the scroll settings as well.. at least there should be a watch for height and width parameters. Can you add that?

Answer (score -2):

Did you try adding this code?

```
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
    axis:"x" // horizontal scrollbar
});

$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
    axis:"yx" // vertical and horizontal scrollbar
});
```